# Scatterplot and Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am still quite new to shiny and ggplot so I am not sure what is causing the problem and I have posted different problems with this code previously however I have come across a new issue... when I run the code my plot does not appear and instead I get an error: Warning: Error in FUN: object "total_pigs" not found.

I get this error regardless of the options I choose in the `selectInput "x"`function.

I have a separate CSV file within the same directory as the app.R file. The selectInput(s) matches the columns and rows within the CSV, I was hoping that my code would simply read the data stored within it and this will generate my plot points.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
path <- file.path("eu_pigs.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Breeding Numbers 2016 - 2018 (pig)"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput(inputId = "x", 
          label = "Pig Breeds:", 
          choices = c("total_pigs", "female_breeding_herd", 
                      "in_pig_sows", "in_pig_gifts", "other_sows", 
                      "maiden_gilts", "boars_for_service", "other_pigs"),
          selected = "total_pigs"),
selectInput(inputId = "y",
          label = "Year by year change:",
          choices = c(2016, 2017, 2018, sep = ""),
          selected = 2016)
),
mainPanel(
plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
)
)
)

server <- (function(input, output) {
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")) +
aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y) +
geom_point()
})
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I attach an image of my csv file.

[image: image of my csv file]

Comment: can you provide the data? it seems from the image that "total_pigs" is a value in a column, and in this case the plot won't work, as it expects to get a column name

Comment: @DS_UNI my column names are: pig_breeds, 2016, 2017 & 2018

Starting from total_pigs all rows down and across are values, so is the problem with my table formatting in csv rather than shiny/ggplot2?

Comment: please dont use the `ggplot(data = read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")) +` on every call, once is enought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DS_UNI suggests, the issue probably lies with the structure of your data. `ggplot2` wants to work with tidy data, so in this case that would mean each row represents a case, i.e. a year.

Here's what I think you need to do, although this is making some assumptions about what you want the end result to look like!

**Step one:** Read in the csv for data wrangling

```
pigs_data <- read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")
```

**Step two:** Make the first column into row names

```
row.names(pigs_data) <- pigs_data$pig_breeds
pigs_data[1] <- NULL
```

**Step three:** Transpose the data

```
pigs_data <- t(pigs_data)
```

You would then use `pigs_data` in your ggplot data argument.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for... I thought the issue lay with `ggplot2` not my table layout. Thank you and @DS_UNI for clarifying this for me.

Comment: I now get an error stating: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an integer vector is this in reference to making the first column into row names?

Comment: What happens if you change the first line to: `pigs_data <- as.data.frame(read.csv("eu_pigs.csv"))`? If that doesn't work, can you provide more information about what `pigs_data` looks like? If you're using RStudio, does it show up in the Environment pane under Data? What does it look like if you do `View(pigs_data)`?

Comment: Looking at your ggplot code more carefully, I think you might need to do more in terms of defining the data as well, but I don't think that is what this specific error relates to.

Comment: I changed the the first line but the same error still appears. nothing shows under Environment unless I import my dataset there (in which case the csv file of eu_pigs has 8 obs. of 4 variables) and when I type `view(pigs_data)` within the Console I get an different error message `> view(pigs_data)
Error in View : object 'pigs_data' not found
Error in view(pigs_data) : object 'pigs_data' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In view(pigs_data) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation`

Comment: So what happens when you run the first line? Are there any errors or warnings? It sounds like possibly the csv isn't being found where the system expects it to be if it isn't loading it. Is the csv in the working directory? I.e. if you are looking at the files tab and click the Home button, is that where the csv is?

Comment: The csv is under my default working directory of {~Documents/ R Projects} and my app.R file is sitting above the csv file. When I click the Home button both my csv and app.R files disappear the only errors I get are the ones previously mentioned... I am still very new to this so maybe I am out of my depth with this test app and should start again from scratch making sure I cover all basis rather than a patch job.

Comment: OK, that implies that you either need to point to the csv more explicitly using the file path, or set your working directory to the R Projects folder you mention. Here is some stuff on this: http://rfunction.com/archives/1001